# Force function parameter to match some rule

Tags: c++, c++11

Is there any way to "force" a function parameter to follow some rule in C++ ?
For the sake of example, let say I want to write a function which computes the n'th derivative of a mathematical function. Let suppose the signature of the function is this one :

```
double computeNthDerivative(double x, unsigned int n);
```

Now, let say I want to forbid users to input 0 for n. I could just use an `assert` or test the value and `throw` an exception if the user input is 0.
But is there any other way of doing this kind of stuff ?

Edit : Conditions would be set at compile time, but the check must be done at the run-time.

Comment: What kind of way are you looking for? One that's enforced at compile time? If that's what you want then you should be explicit about it.

Comment: The simplest would be to pass it a custom class which takes `n` in the ctor and performs the validation. `double computeNthDerivative(double x, AssertedInt n)`.  Where `AssertedInt` is `class AssertedInt (int n) { validate n }`

Comment: @Brian I edited the question to be more precise.

Comment: @jnbbender Indeed that could be a great way indeed. A kind of policy in fact ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class Policy {
private:
    String myPolicy;
public :
    Policy(String regEx) : myPolicy(regEx) {
    }

    void verify(int n) {
       regEx strtok , sprintf, blah, blah n
};

class Asserted {
private:
    Policy policy;
public:
    Asserted(Policy policy, int n) throw AAAHHHHH {
        policy.verify(n);
    }
};
```

Then finally

```
Asserted assert = new Asserted(Policy("[1-9]", 8))
double computeNthDerivative(2.6, assert);
```

Comment: Kinda like this solution, really fits what I had in mind when asking the question !

Answer (score 5):

You can prevent the use of `0` at compile time, using templates.

```
template <int N>
double computeNthDerivative(double x)
{
  // Disallow its usage for 0 by using static_assert.
  static_assert(N != 0, "Using 0 is not allowed");

  // Implement the logic for non-zero N
}
```

To prevent the use of the function for `0` at run time, it's best to throw an exception.

```
double computeNthDerivative(double x, unsinged int n)
{
   if ( n == 0 )
   {
      throw std::out_of_range("Use of the function for n = 0 is not allowed.");
   }

   // Implement the logic for non-zero n
}
```

Comment: Actually my question was not really clear about wether it should have been at compile or runtime, apologizes. I edited the question to make it more specific. Thanks for the useful input though.

Comment: The check should be made at *runtime*, static assertions are not useful for that. Zouch was not clear about that, though

Comment: @user1978011 he wasn't clear about that in his original question

Comment: @PeterSW I agree, but should the answer remain there as is?

Comment: @user1978011, I agree that the original answer doesn't serve the updated question. Updated the answer.

Answer (score 1):

I think the best way here is to throw an exception. This is what exceptions are for, even the name seems to suggest this.

As to the `assert` macro, there is one important caveat. If you use the `assert` macro, the program will abort if the assertion is not met. However, if you ever make a *release* build where the `NDEBUG` macro is set, all **assertions** will be **removed** during compilation. This means that you cannot check for valid user input with this macro (because you *should* build a release build).

Answer (score 0):

The only rules are that you give in. If users are the ones that you want to restrict, you have to check what they give in. 
Same goes for the functions, however in your case what you showed as an example it is better to check the variable after the cin (or whatever imput you prefer) rather than checking it in the function itself. For this i would just go 
    if n!=0;
your function
    else break;

Comment: The idea would rightly be not do the check in the function itself, but to let the function writer make his own "policy" (don't know if it is the right term), and so would not depend on the input (user, algorithm, ...)

Answer (score 0):

So if you are looking for a "Policy" based solution you could create a separate class which accepts a defining regular expression (or whatever you define as a policy) and the input, in this case `n`, which would then be used as the input to your function.